# how can i use a string in sql select where

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

I have a function like this

```
function get_visits($date)
{
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM visits WHERE v_date=$date";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $s = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $s;
}
```

I call this with this code

```
$date = '2021/08/08' ;
$visits = get_visits($date);
```

In SQL I have a column called `v_date`, that have a date

If we store phrase 1 or any phrase like this in that cell and `$date=1;` then my code work. Otherwise, it's not.

Comment: Congrats, you just SQL injected yourself. Look up prepared statements.

Comment: Format your date to '2021-08-08'.